# Check multiple strings for value and return the one with value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following code:

```
preg_match("/Total Payout:(.*)/", $comments, $airbnb_total_payout);
preg_match("/Payout:(\s+[^\s]+)/", $comments, $airbnb_per_night); //price per night
preg_match("/Total reservation amount:(\s+[^\s]+)/", $comments, $booking_total); //booking price
```

Only 1 of those 3 will have a value. what function can i write to check:

```
$airbnb_total_payout[1]
$airbnb_per_night[1] 
$booking_total[1]
```

Which one of them has the value? and return only it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try a series of if statements:

```
function getValue($comments,$airbnb_total_payout,$airbnb_per_night,$booking_total) {
     if(preg_match("/Total Payout:(.*)/", $comments, $airbnb_total_payout)) return $airbnb_total_payout[1];
     if(preg_match("/Payout:(\s+[^\s]+)/", $comments, $airbnb_per_night)) return $airbnb_per_night[1];
     if(preg_match("/Total reservation amount:(\s+[^\s]+)/", $comments, $booking_total)) return $booking_total[1];
     return false; // Return value if none of the conditions are met above.
}
```

To call the function use:

```
$myValueResult = getValue($comments,$airbnb_total_payout,$airbnb_per_night,$booking_total);
```

$myValueResult would then have the resulting value of the function.

Comment: And what variable will hold the finished result with the value?

Comment: @IlanHasanov You would call the function like: $myValue = getValue($comments,$airbnb_total_payout,$airbnb_per_night,$booking_total); then $myValue would contain the result.

Comment: I want something like global function so i can use it all the time

Comment: @IlanHasanov What do you mean? You can reuse the function over and over again, and based on the parameters that you give it, it will return the appropriate results.

Answer (score 0):

You've already got the code. You can just throw it in a function.

```
function getValue ($comments) {
    preg_match("/Total Payout:(.*)/", $comments, $airbnb_total_payout); 
     if (strlen( $airbnb_total_payout[1]) > 0)
        return  $airbnb_total_payout[1] ;

    preg_match("/Payout:(\s+[^\s]+)/", $comments, $airbnb_per_night); //price per night 
     if (strlen( $airbnb_per_night[1]) > 0)
        return  $airbnb_per_night[1] ;

    preg_match("/Total reservation amount:(\s+[^\s]+)/", $comments, $booking_total); //booking price
     if (strlen($booking_total[1]) > 0)
        return $booking_total [1];
    return false;
}
```

(From phone so watch for mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    if($airbnb_total_payout[1] != ""){
        echo $airbnb_total_payout[1];
    }elseif($airbnb_per_night[1] != ""){
        echo $airbnb_per_night[1] ;
    }elseif($booking_total[1] != ""){
        echo $booking_total;
    }else{
        echo "Nothing has a value";
    }
```